# PlaceResult object returns latitude/longitude as object, not sure how to get them individually

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm testing out the Google Places autocomplete feature here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

I want to get the latitude and longitude of the Place, but I'm having some troubles. When I use the following code:

```
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
console.log(place.geometry.location);
```

I get this returned:

[image]

When I use it in an infoWindow like this:

```
infowindow.setContent('
<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + place.geometry.location);
```

`place.geometry.location` is then displayed like this:

> (53.539834, -113.49402099999998)

All I want to do is get the lat and lng separately. `place.geometry.location.lat` doesn't work. Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can use like this.

```
var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

Comment: The Place Details JSON object looks like this: https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details

Comment: It didn't work for me if you search for 'The Shard, London' :|

Comment: This is ridiculous. The JSON response is documented here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResponses Why on earth would they replace fields `.lat` and `.lng` from the JSON response with methods `.lat()` and `.lng()`? (these are the only fields on the JSON that are replaced with the methods)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
var LatLng = place.geometry.location.toJSON();
```

Comment: I was unsure if this is a public API but it seems to be: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me.

```
marker.setIcon(image);

marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

var address = '';
if (place.address_components) {
    address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
    ].join(' ');
}
alert(place.geometry.location.lat());
alert(place.geometry.location.lng());
infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the **LAT** and **LONG** from the **PLACES** object.

Like this :

```
const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.inputNativeElement.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement);

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    let cus_location = {
        lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
        long: place.geometry.location.lng()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### you can bring the values to desired html object as well

`var place = autocomplete.getPlace(); $('#latitude').val(place.geometry['location'].lat()); $('#longitude').val(place.geometry['location'].lng());`